# Angularjs label showing object Object?

Tags: angularjs

I am creating a program which generates a quote every time you press the button 'Generate quote'. I am using this API to get the quotes:
https://thesimpsonsquoteapi.glitch.me/quotes

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <h1>Quote Generator</h1>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.js"></script>

    <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="quoteGenerator">

<button id="btn" type="button" ng-click="generateQuote()"> Generate quote</button>

<button id="btn1" type="button" ng-click="test()"> Test</button>
<br>
<label  id="label" for="btn" ng-model="label"></label>
</body >
</html>
```

app.js:

```
var app= angular.module('myApp',[]);
app.controller('quoteGenerator',['$scope','$http', function ($scope, $http) {
var html="https://thesimpsonsquoteapi.glitch.me/quotes";
    $scope.generateQuote=function generateQuote() {
        $http.get(html)
            .then(function(data) {
                $scope.data = data;
                console.log($scope.data);
                document.getElementById("label").innerHTML=data;
    })
    }

}])
```

At the moment in the console log I am getting each object's details like character name, quote etc and on the label I am getting 'object Object'. But how do I retrieve simply the quote and print it onto the label.

Comment: if you notice the structure of the data object that you receive from API, you should be using `data.data[0].quote`. Also just use it via scope, no need to set innerHTML

Answer (score 0):

In Angular you should not modify the DOM directly. So remove this line:

```
      document.getElementById("label").innerHTML=data;
```

Instead, change the HTML of the label like so:

```html
<label id="label" for="btn">{{data[0].quote}} - {{data[0].character}}</label>
```

The data you get is structured object, you need to get into each object in list and each property of it to show value inside template like above.

Answer (score 0):

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <h1>Quote Generator</h1>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.js"></script>

   
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="quoteGenerator as vm">

<button id="btn" type="button" ng-click="generateQuote()"> Generate quote</button>

<button id="btn1" type="button" ng-click="test()"> Test</button>
<br>

<p>Output Message : {{label}}</p>
</body >
<script>
var app= angular.module('myApp',[]);
app.controller('quoteGenerator',['$scope','$http', function ($scope, $http) {
var html="https://thesimpsonsquoteapi.glitch.me/quotes";
 $scope.label = 'hello';
    $scope.generateQuote=function() {
        $http.get(html)
            .then(function(data) {
                $scope.data = data;
                console.log($scope.data);
                $scope.label = data.data[0].quote;
    })
    }

}])
</script>
</html>
```